# Search, Insert, Delete and DeleteLast operations in logN

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

What can be best suited data structure that supports the following operations in O(log n) time:

```
search(x) ﬁnds the element with key x 
insert(x) insert an element with a key x    
delete(x) delete an element with a key x    
deleteLast() removes the most recently inserted element
```

I know that a binary search tree can handle first three operations pretty good. But how to handle fourth query. If BST is not a good solution than also tell what can be best suited data structure for handling all four queries.

Comment: Use a BST, and if you only want to be able to remove the very last insert, just remember what the last insert was. Otherwise, use a stack to remember all inserts.

Comment: hint: you can use a linked list between the nodes which tells you the insertion order.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut How ? Can you explain please. I was thinking it with linked list

Comment: @G.Bach How stack will help ? Will complexity be still log N ?

Comment: Im with @ThomasJungblut. Think of the BST as holding the data in the leaves, and each leaf ALSO (un related to the tree) points to the item inserted before it.

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov I too agree with him !! But approach is not clear in my mind

Comment: If you are familiar with Java's have a look on [LinkedHashMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java) The idea is similar (use linked list and a set DS) - main difference is the DS implementation is a hash table, and not a tree.

Comment: @amit Can you explain it in terms of tree ? or some example will be suficient

Comment: Your question is missing a part of the specs: after deletion of the most recent, should deletion of the most recent still be possible (deleting the before-last) ?

Comment: You might want to check out my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676254/is-it-possible-to-create-a-map-that-has-arraylist-properties-with-logn-complex/30685044#30685044. I'm still not convinced it's the best that can be done, but I think it works, and allows lookup of the kth most recently inserted node.

Answer (score 3):

Credit to @ThomasJungblut for bringing this solution up.

First, build a BST to hold the information you need in the leaves of the tree.
This in it self solves the search, insert & delete requirements.
To address the "delete most recently inserted element" requirement we add to the structure of each leaf `prev` & `next` fields, so this:

```
struct leaf
{
    int key;
    INFO_STRUCT info;
}
```

Becomes this:

```
struct leaf
{
    int key;
    INFO_STRUCT info;
    leaf *prev;
    leaf *next;
}
```

And except for holding the root of the BST, also hold `leaf *last`. Every time a new element is added, it point to the one before and `last` is updated.

**Note:** This addition only helps finding the requested item, the deletion itself takes `log(n)`.

**EDITED** thanks to @AlexeiShestakov

Comment: What about changes in all four operations ? Post something about them. How tree is constructed.

Comment: So last operation is log^2n ?

Comment: @EdwardDoolittle - the same way you update the deletion of an element from a linked list. (which is what you have here)

Comment: I think that double linked list should be used otherwise the delete operation will have O(n) complexity.

Comment: Why do you say that information is stored in leafs? A BST can store information in any node, usually there isn't a distinction between internal and leaf nodes.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves - true, but the concept of doubling data structures on each node is usually easier to comprehend when the nodes are neatly placed in a line.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can maintain a separate temporary pointer to the parent element of the most recently inserted node.This pointer can be used to delete the most recently inserted element.

I hope this may help!

Comment: Can you add a bit more explanation ?

Comment: Sorry, but this solution fails if you have two consecutive "delete latest element" commands.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned to get operations in O(log n) time.
So it can be done using AVL_TREE and a doubly linked list by maintaining a ***dualLink(biLink)*** b/w the node in Tree and it's corresponding node in doubly linked List.

Insertion will insert a node as `mynode` with SOME data with key as x and a link (reference to corresponding node as `LN` in double linked list) in Tree ***where the corresponding node of double linked list*** is  a node with reference to that node of Tree and will be inserted at front of double linked list so that `firstLink` variable of double linked list will always refer to **recently inserted element** ::
1.) insert(x):: Insert data with key as x in AVL Tree.
First create a doubly linked node as  LN
Now a Tree node as mynode
Now maintain a bilink between both nodes
2.) delete(x):: For deleteing a node from Tree
First find that node in Tree
Now delete that node's referenced doublyLinked node first and
than delete that node in Tree.
3.) deleteLast():: For This Simply Find the referenced node of Tree which is being refernced by first node of doublyLinked List (firstLink).
Now delete that node by calling delete(firstLink.mynode.key) function.
4.) search(x):: This is simple .

Time Complexity of All Above 4 Operations is in O(Logn) because all the operations performing on doublyLinkedList are in O(1) and AVL_TREE always gives O(Log n) Time Cost in above operations.

For AVL_TREE, download it from https://github.com/vivekFuneesh/AVL_TREE

Hope,This Will Help.
***Also, I am habitual of coding in java so below code is in java language***

```
class MyClass{
  /* Create first and last reference to double link list */

  static LinkNode firstLink=null,lastLink=null;

  /* Create root of Complete BST i.e. AVL Tree */

  static node rootAVL=null;

  public static void main(String[] arg){

  }

  /*To remove most recently inserted element in O(Log n) ,just delete element referenced by firstLink.myNode*/
  static void deleteLast(){
    if(firstLink==null){System.out.println("EMPTY TREE");}
    else{
      deletenode(firstLink.myNode.key,rootAVL,rootAVL);   
    }

  }


  /* Insert into AVL Tree a node by maintaining a double reference to and fro b/w AVL Tree's node and corresponding doubly linked list node. */
  /* Time Complexity:: O(Log n) */


  static void insert(int key,int data){
    LinkNode LN=new LinkNode();
    node mynode=new node();
    mynode.key=key;
    mynode.data=data;
    mynode.myLink=LN;
    LN.myNode=mynode;
    /* Insert double linklist node at first*/
    /* Time Complexity:: O(1) */
    insertLink(LN);
    /* Now insert mynode in AVL Tree using mynode.key as key. */

  }  

  /* delete node from AVL Tree in Time Cost ::O(Log n)*/


  static void deletenode(int key,node node,node root){
    if(node!=null){
      if(node.key==key){
        /* First remove it's corresponding doublyLinkednode */
        /* Time Complexity:: O(1)*/
        deleteLink(node.myLink);
        /*Now delete this node in Time Complexity:: O(Log n)*/

      }
      else if(key<node.key){
        deletenode(key,node.left,node);
      }
      else{deletenode(key,node.right,node);}
    }
  }


  /* Your delete(x) function in O(Log n) */
  static void delete(int key){
    if(rootAVL!=null){
      node MYNODE=null;
      /* First find that node with key as key then::delete doublylinked node corresponding to that node then:: delete that. */
      deletenode(key,rootAVL,rootAVL);
    }
    else System.out.println("EMPTY_TREE");
  }


  /* Delete LinkNode ln in Time Cost Of O(1) */


  static void deleteLink(LinkNode ln){
    if(firstLink==null){
      System.out.println("ERROR");System.exit(1);
    }
    else{
      if(firstLink==lastLink){  
        firstLink.myNode=null;  
        firstLink=lastLink=null;
      }
      else if(ln==lastLink){
        ln.left.right=null;
        ln.myNode=null;
        lastLink=ln.left;
        ln.left=null;
      }
      else if(ln==firstLink){
        firstLink.right.left=null;
        firstLink.myNode=null;
        firstLink=firstLink.right;
        firstLink.right=null;
      }
      else{
        ln.left.right=ln.right;
        ln.right.left=ln.left;
        ln.right=ln.left=null;
      }
    }
  }
  /*Insert at First in O(1) so that recently inserted element will always be referenced by  variable firstLink */


  static void insertLink(LinkNode ln){
    if(firstLink==null){
      lastLink=firstLink=ln;
    }
    else{
      firstLink.left=ln;
      ln.right=firstLink;
      firstLink=ln;
    }
  }

}
```

Data Structure for AVL_TREE Node

```
/* An AVL_TREE Node */

class node{
  int key=0;
  int data=0;
  int height=0;/* For maintaining height in AVL Tree*/
  node left=null,right=null;
  LinkNode myLink=null;
}
```

Data Structure For DoublyLinked List Node

```
/* A double LinkList node */  
class LinkNode{
  LinkNode left=null,right=null;
  node myNode=null;
}
```