# Two keys BST based datastructure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

I need to store boxes with square base (represented by base side, and height), in data structure with operations: insert, delete and search for a minimal volume box with both side and height values not less than a given box.
The data structure should be based on binary search trees, so I can simply balance them (red black/AVL). I figured out one tree is not enough, so I am trying to divide the boxes into side values and height values.
Thanks in advance for any proposal, supporting logarithmic time for insert,delete,
and something like n*lg(m) for search (given n,m are number of side and height values).

Comment: Seems like a [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) could help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843120/search-insert-delete-and-deletelast-operations-in-logn/30843422#30843422) for a similar question.

What you need is a node that holds the info that belongs to two trees simultaneously. Each tree is ordered by a different key (width, volume, etc.).

This way, with `O(log n)` complexity you can find a box that matches all requirements.

Comment: can you elaborate, what info the node should hold, where would the node be (third tree?), and how would the search be performed?