# Access tree with ordinal index

Tags: haskell, data-structures, tree, functional-programming, binary-tree

I have a right-biased red-black tree structure that will always be some shape given the total number of elements.

Given the size of elements `k` and an ordinal element `n`, how to write a function to get the n-th element in the tree of size `k`?

```
(size:1)
black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
+ 
+ 


(size:2)
black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
+ 
+ red { 2, 2 }(d:1)
  + 
  + 


(size:3)
black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
+ black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
  + 
  + 
+ black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
  + 
  + 


(size:4)
black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
+ black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
  + 
  + 
+ black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
  + 
  + red { 4, 4 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 


(size:5)
black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
+ black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
  + 
  + 
+ red { 4, 4 }(d:2)
  + black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 5, 5 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 


(size:6)
black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
+ black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
  + 
  + 
+ red { 4, 4 }(d:2)
  + black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 5, 5 }(d:1)
    + 
    + red { 6, 6 }(d:1)
      + 
      + 


(size:7)
black { 4, 4 }(d:3)
+ black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
  + black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
+ black { 6, 6 }(d:2)
  + black { 5, 5 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 7, 7 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 


(size:8)
black { 4, 4 }(d:3)
+ black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
  + black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
+ black { 6, 6 }(d:2)
  + black { 5, 5 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 7, 7 }(d:1)
    + 
    + red { 8, 8 }(d:1)
      + 
      + 


(size:9)
black { 4, 4 }(d:3)
+ black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
  + black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
+ black { 6, 6 }(d:2)
  + black { 5, 5 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + red { 8, 8 }(d:2)
    + black { 7, 7 }(d:1)
      + 
      + 
    + black { 9, 9 }(d:1)
      + 
      + 


(size:10)
black { 4, 4 }(d:3)
+ black { 2, 2 }(d:2)
  + black { 1, 1 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + black { 3, 3 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
+ black { 6, 6 }(d:2)
  + black { 5, 5 }(d:1)
    + 
    + 
  + red { 8, 8 }(d:2)
    + black { 7, 7 }(d:1)
      + 
      + 
    + black { 9, 9 }(d:1)
      + 
      + red { 10, 10 }(d:1)
        + 
        +
```

Comment: Instead of storing the depth in each node, try storing the size (or number of left children).

Comment: Just figured it out. Turns out you don't need to store the size (can be calculated based on depth information)

Comment: @Bergi This is only applicable for red black trees. For other trees you have to store the node count.

Comment: Why is this tagged with 'haskell'?

Comment: Because Haskell programmers love this.

Comment: That doesn't seem like a good enough reason to add a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote everything down on a napkin and figured it out. For red black tree you do not need to track the number of nodes on the left because if it's right biased (should be) then the number of left nodes will always form a mersenne series ( 1, 3, 7, 15, 31 ...) or `2^depth -1`.

With that in mind we can write down the logic to recursively get the node. This is the correct implementation in elixir. For [package](https://github.com/rickyhan/rbtree/blob/master/lib/rbtree.ex)

```
def nth(%Rbtree{node: r}, n), do: do_nth(r, n)
defp do_nth({_,h,k,v,l,r}, n) do
  l_count = left_count(h)
  cond do
    l_count > n ->
      case l do
        nil -> {k,v}
        _ -> do_nth(l, n)
      end
    l_count == n -> {k,v}
    true ->
      case r do
        nil -> {k,v}
        _ -> do_nth(r, n - l_count - 1)
      end
  end
end
defp left_count(1), do: 0
defp left_count(0), do: 0
defp left_count(h), do: :math.pow(2,h-1)-1 |> round
```